# Memory profiler is being disabled while running Chrome dev-tool on Node inspector

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, node-inspector

I am trying to find away to analyze the memory consumption in a NodeJS application. I am trying to use Chrome dev-tool on top of node inspector. It's quite basic to start and I am listening on default 9229 port as suggested [here](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/).

After connecting to the port from chrome, I can see the consoles and files under Node but I am unable to run memory snapshots. It's just disabled.

Opened the inspect screen and clicked on the inspect.

[image: Opened the inspect screen]

Then I see these options completely disabled.

[image: disabled 1]
[image: disabled 2]

On hover of record button, I see a message "Another profiler is already active" which I don't have a clue to.

What could be the underlying issue here?

**System specifications**

Chrome - 83.0.4103.97

OS - Windows 10

Node - 8.9.4

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after trying out different versions, new Microsoft edge, I found out that it's an issue with version incompatibility.

I tried with Node 9.11.1 and it didn't work.
But at end switched to 12.16.1 and it works there. For now I assume chrome/chromium dev-tools supports higher versions of NodeJS.

Answer (score 0):

I also found that the platform needs to be the same.

That is to say, if you run nodejs on Linux, you also need to run Chrome on Linux.